# How to display lay out in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

[image]

I want to display this opportunity page please tell me how to create it.

Comment: Have you already tried something ? If it needs to look exactly like that you'll need to do most of it in custom html and styling. May I remind you that this community is here to help you solve your problems when you get stuck, but not to do your work for you.

Comment: I am asking the way i am not told like that

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Salesforce and Visualforce framework it's good to go through some how to documents. Below are some of them.

1. [An Introduction to Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce)
2. [Building Visualforce Pages Using the Standard Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Building_Visualforce_Pages_Using_the_Standard_Controller)

As it looks like if you need to add your developed visualforce page into a page layout, refer below links (also you can find lot more).

1. [Adding a Visualforce Page to a Page Layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/systems-integrator/2008/11/adding-a-visualforce-page-to-a-page-layout.html)
2. [How to embed Visual Force page in a page layout](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005105&language=en_US)